# How to use character_limiter or word_limiter

Tags: javascript, php

I'm **PHP** newbie and can't find a solution for this:

My website prints correctly a product description, which is sometimes very long. Therefore I would like to limit the text to e.g. 100 words and then display "read more..." which would initiate a java script to display the rest of the text.

Here's what I currently have and what works fine so far without text limitation:

```
<?php echo nl2br($property->description(null, null, true)); ?>
```

And here's what I was advised to do:

```
<?php $long_text = ($property->description(null, null, true)); // STRING!
$word_limit = 250; //your word limit, Int
$output = "";
$parts = explode( " ", $long_text );
foreach( $parts as $index=>$word ){
  $output .= "$word ";
  if( intval( $index ) >= intval( $word_limit ) ){
$output .= "READ MORE LINK";
break;
  }
}
echo $output;
?>
```

As a result the script limits the text indeed to 250 words, but

1. all line breaks and blank lines are ignored
2. "READ MORE..." is just plain text - not a link. I would need the code to call a javascript, to print the rest of the text on the same page.

Can someone please help to finalize this last part ?

Comment: What is `word_limiter`?

Comment: A good, easy-to-use alternative is Shave: [https://github.com/dollarshaveclub/shave](https://github.com/dollarshaveclub/shave)

Comment: @u_mulder it's part of CodeIgniter: [https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/welcome.html](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/welcome.html)

Comment: Really depends on behavior you want

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple sample code that would do the trick

```
$long_text = "Your very long description"; // STRING!
$word_limit = 100; //your word limit, Int

$output = "";
$parts = explode( " ", $long_text );
foreach( $parts as $index=>$word ){
  $output .= "$word ";
  if( intval( $index ) >= intval( $word_limit ) ){
    $output .= "READ MORE LINK";
    break;
  }
}
echo $output;
```

What it does is make an array of words, and when it hits the limit count of words it adds the "Read more link" and exits the loop, then echoes the output. It is not the most efficient solution but I hope it structures your problem well enough to aid in solving the problem.

Comment: 25r43q I have edited my post above after your kind advise and some experiments, but I'm not yet fully done. Please look at my edit. THX.

Comment: The code should join your words with a space between them. The "READ MORE LINK" is a string that you generate according to your standard. To fix linebreaks you could write: echo str_replace( "\n", "<br/>", $output ); in the end.

Comment: I hope not to bother you too much... I have added your code to fix linebreaks and that works perfect. THX again. The big question for me is: How do I replace "READ MORE LINK" with a command that would open up the rest of the hidden text on the same page ?
In another instance of my script it printed the rest of the text in another page opening the "details tab" of that page with this command:

`<a href="javascript:;" onclick="tabs.expandit('details_tab');"><span class="seemore"><?=_e("see more &raquo;")?></span></a>`

Comment: Describe <?=_e("see more &raquo;")?>, is that a php-method? If so, use: $output .= '<a href="javascript:;" onclick="tabs.expandit(\'details_tab\');"><span class="seemore">'._e("see more &raquo;").'</span></a>';

Answer (score 0):

> Do the word-warp and take the 1st line

```
$text = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
$newtext = wordwrap($text, 100, "<br />\n");
$first_line=explode("<br />\n",$newtext);
echo $first_line[0];
```

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/0tqt-a558